# Prove that if that if $p > \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}$ where $n \in\Bbb N$*; then $p² \ge 4n + 2$

Tags: solution-verification

Here's what I tried:

$$p > \sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}$$
$$p² > (\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1})²$$
$$p² > 2n + 1 + 2\sqrt{n(n+1)}$$

So we need to prove that

$$2n + 1 + 2\sqrt{n(n+1)} > 4n + 2$$
$$2n + 1 - 2\sqrt{n(n+1)} < 0$$
$$n + \frac{1}{2} < \sqrt{n(n+1)}$$
$$n² + n + \frac{1}{4} < n² + n$$
$$\frac{1}{4} < 0$$

Which is absurd. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You mishandled the additive factors of $1$.  And you confused the use of $≥$.

Comment: A good way to track down errors in these things is to pick particular values for $n$ and go through it line by line using those numbers.

Comment: You're on the right track: $p^2 > 2n + 1 + 2\sqrt{n(n+1)} > 2n + 1 + 2\sqrt{n\cdot n} = 4n+1$ and so $p^2 \ge 4n+2$.

Comment: guys i wrongly copied 1 instead of 2. check my edit pls. its 4n + 2 not 4n + 1

Comment: @lhf thanks a lot, that's the solution. You can post an answer and I'll accept it and upvote it.

Comment: @AminGuermazi The original proposition must be wrong, is or use directly the truthnes condition this is a dead end.

Comment: It isn't, you can try any example of n and it'll be correct. The only case where it will be wrong is $n \in Z^-$ @ErdelvonMises

Comment: @lhf, minor quibble: Nowhere is it asserted that $p$ is an integer....

Comment: @BarryCipra, oops, somehow I assumed that $p$ is an integer.

Comment: It's given as an integer. Sorry forgot to state it